# What kind of isometric embedding is this?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

As I am a novice in discrete geometry, I would like some insight concerning the following statement: "Given a convex polyhedron P, it is known that making "cuts", not necessarilly along its edges, we can make a planar figure (called development or unfolding), which is an isometric embedding (as far as intrinsic metric concerns)."

My question:
What is the isometric map here? I only can see some kind of a series of translations and rotations of planes (the faces of the polyhedron P) here, in $\Bbb{R^3}$. Am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: You are on the right track. The isometric map is just given by pasting the local (face-wise) transformations. It will be a piecewise defined function.

Comment: @Massimo Frittelli,  thanks for the feedback,  do you have available any sourse (part of a book , or just lecture notes) that describes this procedure more mathematically rigoursly ? Not just cut and glue things...

Comment: No, I don't have a specific source. Just two remarks. First: cut and glue things are perfectly rigorous. Which is why "piecewise defined functions" are a thing in mathematics. Second: not sure where that statement is from. If it is from a book, then the proof is intentionally left to the reader. The author probably felt that the intuitiveness of the procedure did non justify the amount of formalisation needed. With that being said, there might well be a source where the proof is rigorously done, but I am not aware of such source.

Comment: That you can cut the polyhedron and unfold it is obvious, and only involves rotations with various edges as the axes. There is no need for translations. The trickier part of the result is that you can make the cuts so that once unfolded, the polyhedron doesn't overlap itself.